# Is it possible to use p4convert-svn with a running Perforce server which a needs password to access the Perforce Server

Tags: svn, perforce

In the wiki document on how to use p4convert-svn : [How To use p4convert-svn](ftp://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/tools/p4convert-svn/p4convert-svn.html#section4), it is stated it works only on a Perforce Server which does not need security/password.

The perforce server I am trying on needs an username and password for authenticating into the server. So is it possible to configure the config.txt in a manner by which this tool will work on a perforce server which takes a password?

Currently when I run the jar file I encounter the  com.perforce.p4java.exception.RequestException

Answer (score 0):

The best bet is to run the converter into a new, empty Perforce repository with security level set to 0 (no authentication).  Then, after the migration has completed successfully, you can use the perfmerge tool to merge the results into your live server.